# backup and restore ALL resharper settings

Tags: backup, resharper, settings

How can I backup and later restore (after a clean install) ALL resharper settings?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On XP Resharper stores its settings in:
%userprofile%\Application Data\JetBrains\ReSharper\[R# Version]\[VS Version]

and of Vista/7:
%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\ReSharper\[R# Version]\[VS Version]

where [R# Version] is the version of ReSharper installed (e.g. v4.5) and [VS Version] is your Visual Studio version (e.g. vs9.0).

Just copy all the files from that folder to backup, and put them back there to restore.

Comment: Isn't that a bit dangerous? What if the settings format changes from one minor version (4.5.2 to 4.5.3 or something). Does IntelliJ support this approach?

Comment: I guess I can still do a diff and be relatively save.

Comment: It is dangerous, but since ReSharper cannot export its settings (it only exports code styles), you don't have much to work with. I would doubt the format changes much from version to version. Since the settings are stored in an XML file, any XML parser should ignore anything it doesn't understand, so at worst you would be stuck with ReSharper's defaults.

Comment: Perhaps you could do an XSLT if it's minor setting differences, if it's a major change though it might just be better to go through the whole settings again - which could also be valuable since there may be new features?

Comment: Instead of having different paths for XP vs Vista/7, you can just say %APPDATA% and have the OS figure out the right location.