# Does Resharper 6.1 work with MBUnit?

Tags: resharper, mbunit

Unfortunately Resharper has a long history of breaking MBUnit support with every new release. I noticed version 6.1 has been released, but I can't use it until it works properly with MBUnit.

So, does Resharper still work with MBUnit? I'd try it myself, but last time I did I lost all of my Resharper settings while downgrading, so I thought I'd better ask first this time.

Thanks,

Adrian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no official Gallio release supporting ReSharper 6.1 just yet. However, 6.1 support is a [work in progress](http://groups.google.com/group/gallio-user/browse_thread/thread/50193e45ad60e328?pli=1) and latest [development builds](http://ccnet.gallio.org/Distributables) were known to work with 6.1 EAP - no guarantees yet though.

Answer (score 1):

I have used MbUnit with resharper in the past. With the 6.1 release, I haven't had a chance to test it out yet. I do know that there are some tests simply aren't executed correctly in resharper (row tests I think).

Additionally, you can back up your resharper settings as well.
[Backup Resharper Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175348/backup-and-restore-all-resharper-settings)